# Get all input values for review before submission in multi-step wizard - How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a multi step modal I created, and I have one form input on each tab pane.  (Using Bootstrap Tabs).  On the last step, I want all the form fields to be displayed for review so the user can check everything before clicking submit.

How would I go about grabbing all the input values and appending them to the last page?  The last tab is id #step5.  I tried just using a simple

```
$('#dateReview').append($('#date').val());
```

However that updated the new div ID with the date Immediately, and I need it to update once the user reaches the last step on the wizard.  Or maybe on('change') but I cannot seem to get than working.

Anyone have a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no page refresh involved, then you could do:

```
$("#summary").html($("myForm").serialize());
```

(this assumes everything is within a form).

EDIT:

As requested, here's how you might de-serialize form data:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>serialize()</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" />
        <input type="text" name="lastName" />

        <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="yes" id="ch1">
        <label for="ch1">Yes</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="no" id="ch2">
        <label for="ch2">No</label>

        <input type="submit" >
    </form>    

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("form").on("submit", function(event){
        var formData = $(this).serialize().split("&");
        console.log("You entered:");

        $.each(formData, function(index, value){
          value = value.split("=");

          // Append to div instead of logging to console
          console.log(value[0] + ": " + value[1]);
        })
        event.preventDefault();
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So I would serialize the data on change event, and then append each form element to whatever div I want?

Comment: I'm not sure how your modal works and which events it fires, but when the user clicks through to the final step, you should just be able to grab everything in one go. It would help if you could make a fiddle or post a link.

Comment: I dont know how to unserialize the data, could you show me that? I know how to serialize the whole form, but then how would I unserialize the form and append it to a div?

Comment: Awesome, it works but not for checkboxes or textareas . Anything special needed for them?